# SQL count record with zero relation

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find the id of the players whose name is 'Jack' and the number of games they have played:

```
Select p.id, count(*) as numOfGamePlayed
from player p, game g
where p.name = 'Jack' and p.id = g.id
group by p.id;
```

The problem is, this will only list the players name Jack who have played at least one game. How can I also list those who have not played any games?

Edit: for those player, the numOfGamePlayed must be 0. If I do this

```
Select p.id, count(*) as numOfGamePlayed
from player p LEFT JOIN game g ON p.id = g.id
where p.name = 'Jack'
group by p.id;
```

those who have not played any games will still have numOfGamePlayed displayed as 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop using implicit joins for starters.  This is a bad habit anyway.  Then you can do this:

```
Select p.id, count(g.id) as numOfGamePlayed
from player p
LEFT JOIN game g
 ON p.id = g.id
where p.name = 'Jack'
group by p.id;
```

Comment: +1 Stop using implicit joins!

Comment: but then, the numOfGamePlayed for that player who has not played any games is still displayed as 1, when it should be 0?

Comment: Try my updated version

Answer (score 0):

You need an outer join between player and game

```
SELECT p.ID, 
  COUNT(*) AS numOfGamePlayed
FROM player p
LEFT OUTER JOIN game g
ON p.id = g.id
WHERE p.name = 'Jack'
GROUP BY p.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.id, count(*) as numOfGamePlayed
FROM player p
LEFT JOIN game g ON g.id = p.id
WHERE p.name = 'Jack'
--AND g.id IS NULL
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do count(game.PlayerId) instead of count(*)

[See SQL Fiddle demo here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8013d/11/0)

```
select p.PNAME, g.gameplayed
from player p 
left outer join game g
ON p.pid = g.pid;

Select p.pid, count(g.pid) as numOfGamePlayed
from player p 
LEFT JOIN game g 
ON p.pid = g.pid
where p.pname = 'Jack'
group by p.pid;
```